# How to save a shapefile after transform the crs from the existing shapefile in R?

Tags: r, spatial, shapefile

I am trying with this code but it is not working. Please help me with this issue. Thank you.

```
readshp <- readOGR(file.path(nhgisdir, “file1.shp”))`enter code here`
trshape <- spTransform(readshp, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0”)
writeOGR(trshape, file.path(workdir,”file1_tr.shp"), driver="ESRI Shapefile”) # This one goes  wrong!!
```

Comment: Your code sample is not reproducible and it contains two different types of quotation marks: `”`  and `"`, which inhibits proper delineation of strings

Comment: okay. I am sorry I don’t understand your comment exactly. But do you know how to save a Shapefile after transforming the crs from existing Shapefile? For any example.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specify all required arguments of the functions you are using to make them work. Also make sure you use only one type of quotation marks to open and close your strings. Your question uses two different types `”` and `"`, which probably causes errors since r does not know where your commands start and end.

Now the functions to read shapefiles `readOGR` needs some arguments specified: That is `dsn`, the directory of your shapefiles and `layer`, the actual shapefile but without a file extension. The function `writeOGR` works similarly, but has different behaviour depending on the driver you use. For `ESRI Shapefile`, the argument `dsn` needs to be the filename you want to save your shapefile as including an extension. And layer will be the filename without an extension.

All of this info, and which type of arguments need to be specified for which driver, is in the [documentation of rgdal](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/rgdal.pdf). And there are numerous tutorials out there, e.g. [this one by Dr. Emily Burchfield](https://eburchfield.github.io/files/5_spatial_intro_lab.html)

Finally, here is some example code:

```
library(rgdal)
in_shape <- readOGR(dsn="/path/to/shape/", layer="shapefile") 
transformed_shape <- spTransform(in_shape, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80"))
writeOGR(transformed_shape, dsn="/path/to/shape/exported_shapefile.shp", layer="exported_shapefile", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: Thank you very much.